# Entity Framework 6 - MySQL Query Generates Unnecessary SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

This is my first time using EF 6 as well as MySQL. I came across an annoyance while updating my LINQ statement from explicitly using joins to using navigation properties to fetch related data.

Here is the statement I'm executing to get a user and all the user's locations.

```
AspNetUsers.Include("UserLocations")
.Select(u => new { 
    FullName = u.FullName, 
    Locations = u.UserLocations.Select(l => l.Title)
})
```

This statement, using LinqPad4, generates the following SQL:

[image: Unnecessary SQL]

Why does it join using a select statement instead of doing a join on the table itself, and why does it add all the location columns to the join when the only column needed is the Title?

Wouldn't the following SQL query be better:

```
SELECT
   u.FullName,
   l.Title
FROM AspNetUsers u
   JOIN UserLocations ul ON u.Id = ul.UserId
   JOIN Locations l ON ul.LocationId = l.LocationId;
```

This is my first time using EF, I have read that in the past the SQL generated has not been so great. I was wandering if this is just one of those cases or if there is something I could do to minimize the SQL generated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you need exactly? I have experienced myself that Entity Framework doesn't necessarily generate the best queries, but you can override those queries if you want to - not that I would really recommend it but it's possible. On MSDN EF Data developer center you can find more info about this.

Comment: Interesting.  The extra columns and subqueries would be optimized away by SQL Server.  However, MySQL materializes subqueries, so this definitely has worse performance in that database.

Comment: hbulens, I want to know if there is a way to generate better MySQL by tweaking my linq query.

Gordon, boo, I was hoping that this was just something I could tweak in LINQ